# Attach draft to thread [G-mail app script]

Tags: google-apps-script

G-mail
My co-workers sending e-mails to ours clients attach me (my e-mail address) as CC. Sometimes I must send e-mail to this same client. To improve my work I create simple add-on to G-mail, to make it faster (code below). It's work. But creating drafts, it taken as new thread. Important! I must create drafts because created e-mail/drafts isn't send immediately. Emails need to be held for later delivery because they may not be sent otherwise. These are reminders or notes, witch I add to draft, and I left to send it later.

```
function cd(e) {

  // Activate temporary Gmail scopes, in this case to allow
  // the add-on to read message metadata and content.
  var accessToken = e.gmail.accessToken;
  GmailApp.setCurrentMessageAccessToken(accessToken);

  // Read message metadata and content. This requires the Gmail scope
  // https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.current.message.readonly.
  var messageId = e.gmail.messageId;
  var m = GmailApp.getMessageById(messageId);

  //Logger.log("cd run");

  var mto = m.getTo(); 
  //var mfrom = m.getFrom();
  //var mtoCC = m.getCc();
  var mSub = m.getSubject();
  var mBody = m.getBody();
  var mAttach = m.getAttachments();
  //var mData = m.getDate();

  var mtoCC = m.getFrom() + ", " + m.getCc();

  //Logger.log("Message ID ="+ messageId);
  //Logger.log("toaddres = " + toaddres);
  //Logger.log("sender = " + sender);
  //Logger.log("toCC = " + toCC);

 // var GDraft = GmailApp.createDraft();
  
  
  var GDraft = GmailApp.createDraft(mto, mSub, "",
   { attachments: mAttach,
      cc: mtoCC,
      htmlBody: "</br>" + mBody  
   }
  );  
  
  return CardService.newComposeActionResponseBuilder()
    .setGmailDraft(GDraft)
    .build(); 

}
```

Question
How to change the code so that draft are displayed in a thread after sending, instead of as separate messages.